# Replace NAs with zeros using ifelse

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I am trying to replace NAs in my variable- called violence- with zeros and create a new dummy variable using `ifelse`. The violence variable has several categories and NAs. The category ignore should be coded 1 but other categories including NAs should be coded 0.  I use the following code:

```
   df$new_variable<-ifelse(is.na(df$violence)=="ignore",1,0)
```

However, the code did not produce any results.

Comment: The code you are checking is logical == "ignore"

Comment: What exactly do you expect `is.na(df$violence)=="ignore"` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is syntax issue in the code

```
is.na(df$violence) == "ignore"
```

will be comparing the logical column derived from `is.na` with "ignore",  instead if the description is as stated in the OP's post - `The category ignore should be coded 1 but other categories including NAs should be coded 0.`, use

```
df$new_variable <- +(df$violence %in% "ignore")
```

Here, we check for values that are "ignore" with `%in%` which returns a logical vector - `TRUE` only for "ignore" and `FALSE` for all others including `NA` (`==` returns `NA` for `NA` values) and then convert to binary with `+` (`TRUE` -> `1` and `FALSE` -> `0`)